# What vehicles offer more than the standard set of controls?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Some vehicles in GTA 4 offered special controls or even missions to start when inside.

I've already found some vehicles in GTA 5 with more than the standard set of controls, but are there more? Or is there a Website that lists them all?

- All Taxis -> Start Taxi Missions with D-Pad right
- Tow Truck -> Left analog stick lowers/raises hook
- Mountain Bike (w/ full suspension) -> R1 does a Bunny Hop

(I would appreciate it if the answer was made into a community wiki so others could append their findings.)

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few:

- Bulldozer: Left analog stick up/down -> raise/lower blade
- Submarine: `A`/`X` (360) [image: X]/[image: Square] (PS3) -> sink/rise
- Convertibles: D-Pad right (when not moving) -> convert between roofed and open-air mode
- Plane from McKenzie Field Hangar: `A` (360) [image: X] (PS3) -> Drop shipment/bombs
- JB700 (a James Bond-type special car):

  - `X` (360) [image: Square] (PS3) -> ejector seat (only works when the appropriate tooltip appears)
  - click left analog stick -> spikes

Answer (score 4):

Another one I found:

- On a racing bike, press `RT` (360) or `R1` (PS3) to lean forward and go/accelerate faster, but with an higher turning radius. Quite useful during triathlons.

Comment: Neat! Pushing the left stick forward does this too, but it's a lot harder to turn at the same time that way. I hadn't tried the right trigger.

Comment: The left stick balances you between leaning forwards and backwards on all two-wheeled vehicles. Lean forward to go faster, lean backward to perform wheelies. I don't know if R1 is exactly the same as the left stick forward. It may be additional, as it is not present on other two-wheeled vehicles (it's rear wheel brake on motorbikes and jump on suspension bikes).